# Nested table docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to push a second table in my main table.
I use the main table to format correct the text: I'm creating a class in java for generate Curriculum, so I need a main table to create a good template

I try to push a 
Tbl element in a Tc (cell element) of main table, but Word gives me error about a wrong template. It ask me if I want open anyway the document: It show correctly the nested table, but I don't want that the error is displayed.

```
    ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

        Tbl mainTable = TblFactory.createTable(2, 2, cellWidthTwips );
        List<Object> rows = table.getContent();
        Tr row = (Tr) rows.get(0);
        List<Object> cells = row.getContent();
        Tc cell = (Tc) cells.get(0);

        Tbl nestedTable = TblFactory.createTable(1, 5, widthTips/columns );
        cell.getContent().add(nestedTable);
```

I tried also

```
Tbl nestedTable2 = factory.createTbl();
```

Where I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MainDocumentPart mdp:

```
int widthTwips = 4788;
Tbl mainTable = TblFactory.createTable(2, 2, widthTwips);
List<Object> rows = mainTable.getContent();
Tr row = (Tr) rows.get(0);
List<Object> cells = row.getContent();
Tc cell = (Tc) cells.get(0);

Tbl nestedTable = TblFactory.createTable(1, 2, 2000);

// You'll get an error in Word if you don't have an empty <p/> after the nested table.
// Since TblFactory.createTable automatically added an empty <p>, add the table before it
cell.getContent().add(0, nestedTable);

mdp.getContent().add(mainTable);
```

See the explanatory comment in the code snippet.

Comment: Adding the nested table at a specific index was the key, well at least in my case.